# Listview in C# does not show any properties

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, properties, frameworks

I'm trying to use a simple ListView. I dragged one in my XAML file, name it, and trying to acces it in code. Yet all the properties like .Column are not available.

When I try to make a listview by code, it doesn't work either. What am I missing here? I added System.Windows.Forms

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListView testView = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();

(System.Windows.Forms.ListView)lsView.Column // Can't find the property at all..
```

Other objects work just fine, like a ListBox for instance. I'm using the WPF .NET Framework

Comment: Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, created a new project, dragged a listView on the window. Called it test as name. Then in Code I type test. and then i can't type column. .items does work...

Comment: Why don't you use the [System.Windows.Controls.ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=netframework-4.8) WPF class?

Comment: Yet I can't find the column property then as well.. Am i missing something. Am I not supposed to get that directly?

Comment: You do know, when you start to type out the control itself, VS will show you what control to add? You definitely shouldn't add `System.Windows.Forms` reference you your `wpf` project; *if you find the need*, give the references aliases to distinguish the namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `System.Windows.Controls.ListView` in WPF. It has a `View` property that you can set to a `GridView` which in turn has a `Columns` property:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ListView testView = new System.Windows.Controls.ListView();
System.Windows.Controls.GridView gridView = new System.Windows.Controls.GridView();
testView.View = gridView;

gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "...", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Property") });
```